# How do I send the value from a radio button to a form?

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework

I've created a form in Angular, which takes sets various fields based on user inputs. The problem is that the form seemingly cannot accept the user input for a radio group, and I don't know how to code it.

I've tried to model the form for a radio group based on my other parts of the form (all of which work).

In my forms, I have:

```
export class FormPage implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup; 

  showID: boolean;
  showName: boolean;
  showBirthday: boolean;
  showSex: boolean;

  constructor(
    private formService: FormService,
    private datePicker: DatePicker,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { 
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      studyID: '',
      name: '',
      dateOfBirth: '',
      sex: '',
    })
  }
```

And in my HTML, things like

```
<ion-item *ngIf="showName">
            <ion-label position="stacked">Name<ion-text color="danger"></ion-text></ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName="name" type="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

are able to set the field, "name", accordingly.

However, doing a radio group for selecting sex, does not work.
 
            
                Sex

```
          <ion-input formControlName="sex">
              <ion-label>Female</ion-label>
              <ion-radio value="female" name="female"></ion-radio>

              <ion-label>Male</ion-label>
              <ion-radio value="male" name="male"></ion-radio>
          </ion-input>
    </ion-radio-group>
```

I'd like for the selected radio button's value to be sent to the correct field of "sex" in my form.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your radio group inside ion-list component and place radio-group button on ion-list.Then use same name for ge

> **RadioGroup**
>
> A radio group is a group of radio buttons. It allows a user to select
>   at most one radio button from a set. Checking one radio button that
>   belongs to a radio group unchecks any previous checked radio button
>   within the same group

```
<ion-radio-group>
        <ion-list formControlName="sex" radio-group>
            <ion-radio-group>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Female</ion-label>
                    <ion-radio value="female" name="sex"></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Male</ion-label>
                    <ion-radio value="male" name="sex"></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-radio-group>
        </ion-list>
</ion-radio-group>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-ionic-radio-button-group-zik11r

Comment: Thanks, but while it works in StackBlitz, it doesn't work in my own code. I get the following error: "Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'sex'", which is because I am binding formControlName="sex" to ion-list.

Comment: It works when I change <ion-list formControlName="sex" radio-group> to <ion-input formControlName="sex" radio-group>. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.myForm.controls['sex'].setValue(sex);
```